# Expected value and covariance of vector of Bernoullis

Tags: distributions, expected-value, covariance, bernoulli-distribution

I have seen this in Bishop's book (page 445) but I can't understand why.

If I have a *vector* of $D$ binary variables  (the components of the product are independent random variables):
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{D}  \mu_{j}^{x_{j}} (1 - \mu_{j})^{1-x_{j}} 
$$
How do I calculate the mean and covariance?
$$
\mathbb{E}[\pmb{x}] = \pmb{\mu}
$$

$$
 cov[\pmb{x}] = diag(\mu_{j}(1-\mu_{j})) 
$$

Comment: Mean and covariance of what? Could you clarify how the $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\mu}$ relate to the product?  Also, it might be useful to give a reference to the book

Comment: I edited the question, hope I make sense now @JuhoKokkala

Comment: Are the variables independent?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes

Comment: @JoeoCaetano  How is the part "I have the product of D binary variables" related to the part of    (I suppose the  "product" is actually the joint probability and are you asking about the mean and covariance of the vector of the D binary random variables, but this is not made clear in the question)

Comment: Regardless of independence or not, this product has only $2^D$ possible values, so for small $D$ you can compute the expectation using the usual formula: sum the values times their probabilities. For larger $D$ you need to seek simplifications of the sum, whose possibility depends on the joint distribution.  (This assumes you really do want to find the expectation of this product, which in most contexts is used to express the likelihood of a set of $D$ independent Bernoulli variables.)

Comment: Please note that new information (independence) should be given as an edit, not as a comment. For now I will do the edit!

Comment: What are you actually asking?  You seem to know the mean and covariance.  Do you want to know how to derive it?

Comment: @jbowman yes that's it! Sorry if I was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **product** of $D$ random variables; what you have is a **vector** $\mathbf X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_D)$ of $D$ Bernoulli random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_D$ with *parameters* $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_D$ respectively (and hence *means* $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_D$ respectively). Thus, we have 
$$E[\mathbf X] \stackrel{\small{\text{def}}}{=} \big(E[X_1], E[X_2], \ldots, E[X_D]\big) = (\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_D) \stackrel{\small{\text{def}}}{=} {\pmb{\mu}}.\tag{1}$$ 
We are also told that the probability mass function of $\mathbf X$ (equivalently, the *joint probability mass function* of the $D$ random variables) is
\begin{align}p_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf x) \stackrel{\small{\text{def}}}{=} 
p_{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_D}(x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_D)
= \prod_{j=1}^{D}  \mu_{j}^{x_{j}} (1 - \mu_{j})^{1-x_{j}}.
\tag{2}\end{align}
But the right side of $(2)$ is readily recognized as being equal to
$\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{D} p_{X_j}(x_j)$ which tells us that
$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_D$ are *independent* random variables, and so
$$\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_j) = \begin{cases}\mu_i(1-\mu_i), &j=i,\\
0, &j\neq i,\end{cases}\tag{3}$$
leading to
$$\mathrm{cov}(\mathbf X) \stackrel{\small{\text{def}}}{=} \big[\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_j)\big]_{i,j} = \mathrm{diag}\big(\mu_1(1-\mu_1),\mu_2(1-\mu_2),\ldots, \mu_D(1-\mu_D)\big).\tag{4}$$